# Deferencia entre $this->$algo y $this->algo en PHP

Tags: php, poo

Estoy pasando un desarrollo en php nativo a php orientado a objetos, pero en este momento tengo varias dudas, algunas las logro resolver por mi cuenta pero tras no.

Llegado a una parte del codigo y buscando un poco en la web me tope con esto

```
$this->algo
$this->$algo
```

me gustaria saber cual es la diferencia entre estas dos y cual es su uso. si bien $this->algo accedo a la info de la propiedad "algo", con $this->$algo que es lo que haria.

Desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el primer caso `$this->algo` quiere decir que estás accediendo a la propiedad `algo` de la clase.

En el segundo caso `$this->$algo` quiere decir que estás accediendo a la propiedad que tenga la variable `$algo`, si la clase no tiene la propiedad te arrojará un error.

Dada la clase `Car`, en el primer `echo` vemos como accedemos normalmente a la propiedad de la clase.
En el segundo `echo` vemos como utilizamos el contenido de una variable para acceder a esa propiedad.

Se podría considerar como "dinámico" el ultimo caso, ya que es una forma de acceder a una propiedad de la clase mediante un `string`

```
<?php
    class Car{
        public $brand = 'suzuki';
        public $model = 'swift';
    }

    $car = new Car();
    $brand = 'model';
    echo $car->brand;
    echo $car->$brand;
```

Si reemplazamos el contenido de la variable `$brand` se traduce en `$car->model`, ya que el contenido de `$brand` en realidad es `model`, el nombre de la variable es para demostrar que en realidad no tiene relación alguna con la propiedad de la clase.

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias por tu explicación.

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

En PHP `$this` es usada como una *pseudo-variable* para hacer referencia al contexto actual del objeto. Y se usa única para las **propiedades** y **métodos no estáticos** de la clase. Lo único válido con respecto a `$this` es: `$this->propiedadNoEstatica` o `$this->metodoNoEstatico()`. El uso de `$this->$propiedad` es incorrecto. La `$` se usa con `self`, para invocar las propiedades estáticas de la clase.

---

Todo viene claramente explicado en el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.basic.php):

> La pseudovariable `$this` está disponible cuando un método es invocado
>   dentro del contexto de un objeto. `$this` es una referencia al objeto
>   invocador (usualmente el objeto al cual el método pertenece, aunque
>   puede que sea otro objeto si el método es llamado [estáticamente](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php)
>   desde el contexto de un objeto secundario). A partir de PHP 7.0.0, la
>   llamada estática a un método no estático desde un contexto
>   incompatible resulta en que `$this` no esté definido dentro del
>   método. Una llamada estática a un método no estático desde un contexto
>   no compatible está obsoleta desde PHP 5.6.0. A partir de PHP 7.0.0,
>   una llamada estática a un método no estático está obsoleta en general
>   (incluso si se llama desde un contexto compatible). Antes de PHP
>   5.6.0, tales llamadas ya ocasionaban un aviso de estrictez.

En resumen:

- `$this->propiedadNoEstatica` se usa para invocar propiedades no estáticas dentro del objeto
- `$this->metodoNoEstatico()` se usa para invocar métodos no estáticos dentro del objeto
- `self::$propiedadEstatica` se usa para invocar propiedades estáticas (nótese la `$` en el nombre de la propiedad).
- el uso de `$this->$propiedad` o de `$this->$metodo()` **es erróneo**.
- desde fuera de la clase se usa la misma notación, únicamente se cambiará `$this` o `self` por el nombre de la instancia. En ese caso, como es lógico, para el caso de `self` el nombre de la instancia irá con `$` por ser una variable más de PHP.

Veamos un ejemplo basado en una clase. He puesto comentarios sobre cada cosa:

```
<?php
    class TestClass
    {
        /*
            Los declaramos public a modo de prueba
            en general conviene encapsular
            declarando los miembros private
        */
        public $notStatic;
        public static $yesStatic;

        public function __construct($paramNotStatic, $paramYesStatic) {
            #Nótese la forma de asignar cada propiedad
            $this->notStatic=$paramNotStatic;
            self::$yesStatic=$paramYesStatic;
            echo self::showAllStatic();
        }
        /*
            Este método se invocaría con $this->showAll()
            desde dentro de esta clase
        */
        public function showAll() {
            echo $this->notStatic.PHP_EOL;
            echo self::$yesStatic.PHP_EOL;
        }
        /*
            Este método se invocaría con self::showAllStatic()
            desde dentro de esta clase
        */    
        public static function showAllStatic(){
            echo self::$yesStatic.PHP_EOL;
        }

        public function setNotStatic($newVal){
            $this->notStatic=$newVal;
        }

        public function setYesStatic($newVal){
            self::$yesStatic=$newVal;
        }
    }
```

Hagamos algunas pruebas con esta clase:

```
$mTest=new TestClass('prop. no estática (se usa $this->propiedad)','prop. estática (se usa self::$propiedad)');
$mTest->showAll();
$mTest->setNotStatic("nuevo valor no estático");

$mTest->showAll();

/* 
    Esta llamada, aunque funciona, es obsoleta desde PHP 7
    lanzando un mensaje de Deprecated
    esto por tanto hay que evitarlo
*/
$mTest::setYesStatic("nuevo valor estático, pero no hagas esto");

/*
    Esto en cambio se puede hacer
    no lanza ninguna advertencia
*/
$mTest::showAllStatic();

/*
    Desde fuera del objeto nótese que se reemplaza $this
    por el nombre de la instancia, en este caso $mTest
    y lo mismo ocurre con self, el resto de la notación
    es el mismo
*/
echo $mTest->notStatic;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $mTest::$yesStatic;
```

**Salida por pantalla de la prueba:**

```
prop. estática (se usa self::$propiedad)
prop. no estática (se usa $this->propiedad)
prop. estática (se usa self::$propiedad)
nuevo valor no estático
prop. estática (se usa self::$propiedad)
<br />
<b>Deprecated</b>:  Non-static method TestClass::setYesStatic() should not be called statically in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>54</b><br />
nuevo valor estático, pero no hagas esto
nuevo valor no estático
nuevo valor estático
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudaste mucho

Answer (score 2):

Cuando usas la *pseudovariable* `$this->` de esta forma:

```
$this->some;
```

- Estas haciendo referencia a una propiedad que fue declarada dentro del contexto de una clase en PHP y que será retornada por el método `foo`.
- La propiedad **NO** debe ser estática

Por ejemplo:

```
class Demo
{
    public $name;

    public function foo()
    {
        return $this->name = "algo";
    }
}

$obj = new Demo;
var_dump($obj->foo());
```

Lo cual me daría por pantalla el tipo y valor de dicha propiedad que el método `foo` me esta retornando:

> string(4) "algo"

Sin embargo si ahora yo hago el cambio agregando el identificador de variable **`$`**:

```
return $this->$name = "algo";
```

- Da error de variable *indefinida* debido a que `$this->` tratará de acceder a una propiedad que de hecho en el *contexto* del método **no existe**

Lo cual cambia si yo hago lo siguiente:

```
class Demo
{
    public $name = "algo";

    public function foo()
    {
        $name  =10;
        return $name;
    }
}

$obj = new Demo;
echo $obj->foo();
```

Arrojando en consola:

> 10

Aunque podemos tener un tercer escenario:

- Declaras la propiedad en el contexto de la clase
- Dentro del método `foo` existe la declaración de una variable `$name`
- Esta variable que existe dentro del método la igualamos con la invocación de la propiedad que le pertenece a la clase
- Con lo anterior generaremos por salida el valor de la propiedad haciendo una sobreestrictura que la variable tenia:

Código

```
class Demo
{
    public $name = "algo";

    public function foo()
    {
        $name  =10;
        return $name = $this->name;
    }
}

$obj = new Demo;
echo $obj->foo();
```

Dando:

> algo

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudaste mucho