# ERROR mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ''@'localhost'

Tags: php, mvc, phpmyadmin

estoy intentando implementar un MVC de un sistema para que los usuarios fichen y quede registrado las horas que han trabajado. Me da un error al conectar a la base de datos pero solo cuando creo una clase dedicada a la conexión (antes lo había probado en el mismo html del login para ver si funcionaba, y funcionaba). Os muestro la clase y el error que da, a ver si veis algún error y me dais alguna pista:

```
<?php

class Conexion{

    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $pass;
    private $db;

    public $conexion;
    
    function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db)
    {
        $this->$host= $host;
        $this->$user= $user;
        $this->$pass= $pass;
        $this->$db= $db;
    }

    function conectar()
    {
        $this->conexion = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db)
            or die ("Error al conectar");

        //$this->conexion->set_charset("utf-8");

        return $this->conexion;
    }
}

$c1 = new Conexion("localhost", "root", "", "controlhorario");
$c1->conectar();

?>
```

El error que da es en la línea 22:

```
$this->conexion = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db)
```

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoDAW\config\conexion.php on line 22

Antes lo tenía así y funcionaba:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Control Horario de empleados</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="web\css\style.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center login-page">
       <div class="col-md-12 login-form">
          <form action="?" method="post">
             <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 login-form-header">
               <p class="login-form-font-header">Control<span>Horario</span><p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12 login-from-row">
              <input name="IDEmpleado" type="text" placeholder="ID empleado" required/>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12 login-from-row">
              <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required/>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12 login-from-row">
              <button class="btn btn-info">Entrar</button>
           </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

<?php

    //require_once('config\conexion.php');

    if (!empty($_POST))
    {

        $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "controlhorario");

        $IDEmpleado = $_POST['IDEmpleado'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT ID, Contraseña, Administra from EMPLEADO where ID = '".$IDEmpleado. "' 
        AND Contraseña = '".$password."'");

        $resultado = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if ($resultado > 0) {
            $resultado = $query->fetch_array();
            if ($resultado['Administra'] == 1) {
                header("Location: ./web/view/cabecera_administrador.php");
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: ./web/view/cabecera_vista_empleado.php");
                exit();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Usuario o contraseña erróneos";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: El error te dice claramente que se deniega el acceso por y que no usas password. Y en el código veo que password está en blanco ("").

Comment: Voy a añadir cómo lo tenía antes de separar el código en otro archivo y hacer esa clase, pues es lo mismo y funcionaba. Es un localhost de phpmyadming, el usuario es root y la contraseña vacía (siempre funcionó así)

Comment: Las asignaciones en el constructor de la clase que has creado son erróneas, cuando usas `$this`  no debes usar `$` después de `->`, tienes que ponerlo así: `$this->host= $host; $this->user= $user; $this->pass= $pass; $this->db= $db;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las asignaciones en el constructor de la clase que has creado son erróneas, cuando usas `$this`  no debes usar `$` después de `->`, de modo que `$this->$propiedad` no es nunca correcto (sobre la `$` después de `propiedad`), lo correcto sería `$this->propiedad`<sup>1</sup>.

Si corriges el constructor de este modo debería funcionar, salvo otros errores:

```
function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db)
{
    #Se quitan todas las $ después de ->
    $this->host= $host;
    $this->user= $user;
    $this->pass= $pass;
    $this->db= $db;
}
```

---

1. Para comprender el uso correcto de `$this` puedes consultar la pregunta: *[Deferencia entre $this->$algo y $this->algo en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/341614/29967)*.

Comment: Ja, justo estaba editando esa parte igual.

Comment: @Excorpion creo que este es el núcleo del problema, por eso he ido directo al grano. Vi que luego lo pusiste en la edición de tu respuesta. Si hubieras referido el problema me habría abstenido de escribir una respuesta.

Comment: No pasa nada, yo me centré en mostrarle al usuario como entender su problema, que es lo que el requiere en la publicacion

Answer (score 1):

El error que tienes es el siguiente:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
> ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoDAW\config\conexion.php on line 22

Y quiero que pongas atención a lo siguiente:

```
Access denied for user ''@'localhost'
```

El usuario no está asignado. Por lo que, en tus procesos, este no se está cargando de manera correcta.
Y eso se puede probar solo tirando echos, para ver si cargas o no las variables;

```
function conectar()
{
    echo $this->user." USER</br>"; //Este user, debiese no mostrarte root, por que no carga
    $this->conexion = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db)
        or die ("Error al conectar");

    //$this->conexion->set_charset("utf-8");

    return $this->conexion;
}
```

---

Si realizas un var_dump de $c1, obtienes esto: (puedes ver como se está construyendo mal)

```
object(Conexion)#1 (9) {
  ["host":"Conexion":private]=>
  NULL
  ["user":"Conexion":private]=>
  NULL
  ["pass":"Conexion":private]=>
  NULL
  ["db":"Conexion":private]=>
  NULL
  ["conexion"]=>
  NULL
  ["localhost"]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["root"]=>
  string(4) "root"
  [""]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["controlhorario"]=>
  string(14) "controlhorario"
}
```

---

Para entonces, resolver el problema, debes corregir el constructor, el cual tiene mal hechas las asignaciones.
Estas debiesen ser `$this->algo` y no `$this->$algo`.

Entonces nos quedaría así:

```
function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db)
{
    $this->host = $host;
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->pass = $pass;
    $this->db = $db;
}
```

Y esto nos arroja correctamente el var_dump de $c1.

```
object(Conexion)#1 (5) {
  ["host":"Conexion":private]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["user":"Conexion":private]=>
  string(4) "root"
  ["pass":"Conexion":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["db":"Conexion":private]=>
  string(14) "controlhorario"
  ["conexion"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Ya luego, solo queda hacer el `$c1->conectar();` y funcionará correctamente la conexión.